# Update database after complete payment PayPal

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

ive got no problem with inserting the transaction after puchased is completed.
the problem is how do i update the data.

MySQL table:
USERS:

```
  id |   email        |  credit
----------------------------
  1    user@email.com      2
  2    user2@email.com     1
```

PayPal IPN:

```
$p = new paypal_class;  
if ($p->validate_ipn()) {
  if($p->ipn_data['payment_status'] == 'Completed') {
    $db->query("UPDATE users SET credit='". $p->ipn_data['custom'] . "' WHERE email='" . $p->ipn_data['payer_email'] . "'");
  }
}
```

PAYPAL BUTTON -> hidden(custom) = 5 credit
PAYPAL BUTTON -> hidden(custom) = 10 credit

if `user 1` want to topup their credit, the remaining his credit (2)+PayPal(5)= 7.
instead replacing credit(2) to (5).

Comment: Even if you validated IPN data with validate_ipn(), it's good rule not to trust it at all. Escape your variables before injecting them in SQL commands or use placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that credit is a numeric type field, then:

```
$db->query("UPDATE users SET credit= credit + ". $p->ipn_data['custom'] . " WHERE email='" . $p->ipn_data['payer_email'] . "'");
```

Comment: thanks for the input. how do i get credit(numeric) from? or do i need to create another $db->query to fetch the remaining credit?

Comment: The query has the database perform the math.  `credit = credit + 5', for instance, would increase the value of the credit field by 5.  You could simply replace your line of code for my line of code and it should work as-is.

Comment: Programming (and women) will occasionally surprise you by being absolutely straightforward.  Do not trust it.  :)